# printing first 3 digits of decimal number from user input

Tags: java, double, java.util.scanner, modulo

The prompt says:

> Input a double and print the first three digits after the decimal
> point with a space between them.
>
> Sample run:
>
> Please input a decimal number:
> 67.3424
> Answer: 3 4 2

What I have so far

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please input a decimal number: ");
double hit_n = scan.nextDouble();

double hit_4 = hit_n % 10;
hit_n /= 10;
double hit_3 = hit_n % 10;
hit_n /= 10;
double hit_2 = hit_n % 10;
hit_n /= 10;
double hit_1 = hit_n % 10;

System.out.println(hit_1);
System.out.println(hit_2);
System.out.println(hit_3);
System.out.println(hit_4);
```

The problem with this code is that it keeps printing the decimals added when you input them.

Answer (score 1):

Since, it doesn't say how you do it.  One way is to ignore all the characters before '.', print three characters following '.', and ignore the rest.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
       System.out.print("Please input a decimal number: ");
       char c = 0;
       int count = 0;
       boolean print = false;
        while((c = (char) System.in.read()) != '\n'){
          if (c == '.') print = true;
          else if (print && count++ < 3){
             System.out.print(c);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Please input a decimal number: 5234.25234233
252
```